# How to set pip2 as default pip on Ubuntu 20.04 and later

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

For various compatibility reasons I need to setup `Ubuntu` `20.04` and `22.04` to run both `python2 (pip2)` as well as `python3 (pip3)`, in a way that:

- `python = python2` easy with link with `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python` or `update-alternatives`
- `pip = pip2` hard because package`python3-pip` actually installs `pip` the hard way into `/usr/bin/pip`

This can be fixed with quick and dirty:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/pip
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip2 /usr/bin/pip
```

But once you update the package it reverts back...

`Ubuntu 20.04` was installed like so:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3 python3-dev python3-pip -y
sudo apt install python python-dev -y
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
sudo python2 get-pip.py
rm -f get-pip.py
```

Some useful outputs from machine:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.18
$ python2 -V
Python 2.7.18
$ python3 -V
Python 3.8.10
$ pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
$ pip2 -V
pip 20.3.4 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
$ pip3 -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
$ ls -la /usr/bin/pip*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 365 Jul 13  2021 /usr/bin/pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 367 Jul 13  2021 /usr/bin/pip3
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/pip*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 221 Nov 22 13:53 /usr/local/bin/pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 221 Nov 22 13:53 /usr/local/bin/pip2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 221 Nov 22 13:53 /usr/local/bin/pip2.7
$ which -a pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip
/bin/pip
$ pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
$ /usr/local/bin/pip -V
pip 20.3.4 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Note that I fully understand that `python2` is deprecated and everything should be run in `virtualenv` anyways. Plan is to provide fully compatible environment and eventually switch default `python` and `pip` to version `3`. But in meantime there is a lot of scripts using `pip install` instead of `python -m pip install`.